# Is it possible to get a mouse button (not recognized by xev) working?

Tags: drivers, kernel, mouse

I am using [Microsoft Explorer Touch Mouse](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/explorer-touch-mouse) and I am trying to get two buttons recognized. Mouse, of course, comes with a custom software for Windows and Macosx to customize the buttons, but not for Linux.

Unfortunately, xev just ignores those two button presses.

Is it possible at all to get them recognized? If it is, where do I start?

Answer (score 2):

I'm really no expert on this, but I think there's a way to listen to the low level signals/events you get.

I would unplug/plug the device to figure out where its device is created in the filesystem */dev/input* and try to find a tool that "listens" to this device. Then see how to get this interpreted by X.

Comment: You could also file it as a bug and look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection for info on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with btnx - [btnx - Button Extension](https://launchpad.net/btnx)

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install btnx
```